# CassandraQL allow filtering

Tags: cassandra

I am creating a table in cassandra database but I am getting an allow filtering error:

```
CREATE TABLE device_check (
  id   int,
  checked_at  bigint,
  is_power    boolean,
  is_locked   boolean,
  PRIMARY KEY ((device_id), checked_at)
);
```

When I make a query

```
 SELECT * FROM device_check where checked_at > 1234432543
```

But it is giving an allow filtering error. I tried removing brackets from device_id but it gives the same error. Even when I tried setting only the checked_at as the primary key it still wont work with the > operator. With the = operator it works.

Answer (score 0):

`PRIMARY KEY` in Cassandra contains two type of keys

1. Partition key
2. Clustering Key

It is expressed as 'PRIMARY KEY((Partition Key), Clustering keys)`

Cassandra is a distributed database where data can be present on any of the node depending on the partition key. So to search data fast Cassandra asks users to send a partition key to identify the node where the data resides and query that node. So if you don't give `parition key` in your query then Cassandra complains that you are not querying the right way. Cassandra has to search all the nodes if you dont give it `partition key`. Thus Cassandra gives a error `ALLOW FILTERING` if you want to query without partition key.

With respect to `>` not supported for `partition key`, answer remains same as when you give a range search in your query then Cassandra has to scan all the nodes for responding which is not the right way to use Cassandra.

Comment: So what your saying is that it is not possible to search for values with the > operator?

Comment: Yes >, >=, < . <= not supported in Cassandra for partition key. If you want to run this query you can SELECT * FROM device_check where checked_at > 1234432543 WITH ALLOW FILTERING with this  PRIMARY KEY ((device_id), checked_at). But "ALLOW FILTERING" has serious performance consequences.